# Computer Freezes/Locks Up After Waking from Sleep

Tags: windows-10, ssd, freeze

I bought one of these for my nephew:

https://www.newegg.com/p/N82E16883289016

It works great for him other than about once a day when he wakes it from sleep, the monitor turns on and you can move the mouse for about 5 seconds and then it completely freezes.  The mouse cursor disappears and the system no longer accepts any input and requires a hard reboot to function again. (After the reboot, it seems  to work fine for a couple of sleep cycles before it freezes up again.)

I was reading that the SSD could be the issue, and this PC has an HP M700 SSD.  I can't seem to find any documentation on that piece of hardware, let alone new drivers.

Help?

Here is the HP SSD Info:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked that the CPU fan is seated correctly?

Comment: Since when did this issue start? Did Windows 10 update itself recently? While SSD might be the issue, a bad update that causes more issues can not be ruled out. Not too sure but if Windows had a chance, it might have recorded something in the Event Viewer, not so sure though. Just check it out next time it occurs.

Comment: The problem started not long after I took the PC out of the box and set it all up.  It could have been after a Windows update, but the system came out of the box with Win 10 installed.  The only real events in the Event Viewer are from hard rebooting the system with it complaining about being powered off incorrectly.

Comment: Is the PC still under warranty, can you call PC manufacturer SkyTech? Has it ever woken up from sleep successfully (not freeze up)? Might have to get us more details: motherboard model, BIOS/UEFI version, RAM type, speed, amount of sticks, size, etc.

Comment: It successfully wakes from sleep once or twice after a power button down restart.  I contacted SkyTech and have disabled hybrid sleep on their recommendation. I will put the computer through a few more sleep cycles and see if that resolves the issue. If so, I will update the answers here with the full details of what they suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution appears to be disabling Fast boot and Hybrid Sleep mode.  (NOTE: I have not re-enabled one or the other to see if one solves it instead of both.)

Here are the instructions I received from SkyTech:

To disable Fast Startup:

Open up Power Options in the Control Panel. In Windows 10 you can get there from right clicking on the start menu and going to Power Options
Once there, on the left hand side, click "Choose what the power buttons do"
Click  "change settings that are currently unavailable" up at the top
Down below under the "Shutdown Settings" section you will see "Fast Startup" check-boxed. Uncheck the box
Click OK

To disable Hybrid Sleep:

Open up Power Options in the Control Panel. In Windows 10 you can get there from right clicking on the start menu and going to Power Options
Click "change plan settings" next to your current power plan
Click "change advanced power settings"
Click the + sign next to "Sleep" 
Click the + sign next to "Allow hybrid sleep" and change setting to "off"
Click OK

Comment: For me it was the fast startup. This problem appeared after windows update

Answer (score 1):

If the PC is still under warranty I'd suggest to contact [SkyTech (PC manufacturer)](https://skytechgaming.com/contact-us/).

### REARDING ISSUE - Freeze ups:

- I'd suggest to disconnect SSD then install OS to another drive to see if the issue still occurs. This will isolate if its the SSD or not.
- Disconnect everything from PC except monitor & keyboard. Power on, when it finishes booting press the sleep button, then wake it up by keyboard or pressing button again to see if the issue reoccurs. This will isolate if an external device may be causing issue. If you have no sleep button Windows Power Options can configure the power button to put to sleep (pressed once, not held)
- Maybe boot a Linux live disc (I like [Ultimate Boot CD-UBCD](https://www.ultimatebootcd.com/download.html)) & try to sleep with SSD connected & without SSD connected. This may help isolate if its the PC hardware or something with OS (Windows?), drivers, or SSD. You could try to update the BIOS/UEFI-firmware, also maybe reset that to defaults. I've seen RAM do some funky things so I'd suggest testing that (UBCD), remove all memory except one try to replicate issue then remove that one & try another stick, & adjusting timing in BIOS

### REGARDING SSD:

[Newegg reviews for just SSD](https://www.newegg.com/hp-m700-120gb/p/N82E16820326766?reviews=all) seem to indicate others are having trouble contacting manufacturer. [It appears the company selling/supporting the SSD's is actually **S3+**](https://ssdhp.com/2018/08/27/ssd-hp-m700-2-5-series/). They have an RMA process, but apparently no drivers or firmware. I'd reach out to them: hp.ssd@s3plus.com or [use this contact form page](https://ssdhp.com/contact-us/) & advise your results to help others in your situation since that is the whole point of superuser/stack-exchange.

P.S. It'd be helpful to gather more info on the SSD so people can possibly help you better. [HP has a guide how to gather more info from the SSD](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c02435719)

Comment: Is there anything specific I should gather as far as info goes to help with the post? I will update my question with the details gathered from the HP SSD guide.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue a few years ago and it turned out to be the drive overheating due to a failed case fan.  Check to see you have sufficient airflow and it isn't being heated by other components.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me was to plug mouse on USB 2.0 port.
What was happening to me was that mouse was unresponsive (but with lights on) and keyboard was off after computer would come back from sleep.

Now mouse works after waking up, but I'm still trying to figure out what's happening to the keyboard. It will work only if I change the USB port, no matter if its USB 2 or 3, or restart the computer.
Keyboard disappears from device manager after waking up, along with related Human interface devices list.

I'm using Microsoft's wired 600 keyboard and Mouse.